# Functions with **kwargs

Tags: python, function, arguments

I want to write a Python function `myfun` that accepts only optional parameters, `a` and `b`.

If either one of `a` or `b` is not specified when calling `myfun`, how can I tell `myfun` to use some default value for `a` and `b`?

```
def myfun(**kwargs):

    a = kwargs.get('a', None)
    # if a is not specified, use default a=4.4

    b = kwargs.get('b', None)
    # if b is not specified, use default b=2.1    

    c = 2*a
    d = 3.1*b

    return c, d


c,d = myfun(a=1,b=2)
print c,d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`**kwargs` is used to collect an **arbitrary number** of keyword arguments.  If you only want to accept two, then it is not the right tool to be using.

Instead, you should specify default values for the `a` and `b` parameters:

```
def myfun(a=4.4, b=2.1):
```

Demo:

```
>>> def myfun(a=4.4, b=2.1):
...     print('a={}\nb={}'.format(a, b))
...
>>> myfun()
a=4.4
b=2.1
>>> myfun(a=1)
a=1
b=2.1
>>> myfun(a=1, b=2)
a=1
b=2
>>> myfun(b=2)
a=4.4
b=2
>>>
```

Comment: +1 for example. So what tool should I be using instead? My function is only meant to be a 'toy' problem and I'm working on something a little more complex.

Comment: @MedullaOblongata Its hard for us to know as we dont know what your complex problem is. Maybe you should post another question with the function you are actually trying to write.

Answer (score 0):

set them to a default value:

```
def myfun(a=4.4,b=2.1):
```

There would be no way for a user to know they could set `a` and `b` if you did not add them as keywords in the function definition.

If you were setting a value using `kwargs.get` you would pass the default value to get:

```
a = kwargs.get('a', 4.4) # a = 4.4 if a not in kwargs

b = kwargs.get('b', 2.1)
```